# Attach Elements to side page

Tags: html, css, web

So this is my problem. My webpage has this glaring problem, and I don't know how to fix it. The top and bottom menu bars seem suddenly to want to float in space for some reason.

[image: Up]

[image: down]

How would I fix this in Chrome?

Comment: can you post the css and htnl? Based on the image, it looks like there are magin's around the page. Try setting _html { margin: 0 }_. In most major browsers, the default margin is 8px on all sides

Comment: Can you add a snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many of the comments will suggest, posting the minimum HTML/CSS for the problem will help resolve the issue described. [You can help others reproduce the issue by creating a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

As for the issue described and based on the images provided, it looks like there are magin's around the page. Try setting:

```
html { margin: 0; }
```

In most major browsers, the default margin is 8px on all sides. It is defined in pixels by the user-agent-stylesheet your browser provides.